# Rails - How to record two reference IDs at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Only one out of the two reference ID's is being set in one of my tables.

**schema**

[image]

---

**Models**

**tech.rb**

```
class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :services
end
```

**service_menu**

```
class ServiceMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end
```

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tech
  belongs_to :service_menu
end
```

---

**Controller**

**services_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @service = current_tech.services.build
end

def create
    @service = current_tech.services.build(service_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

private

def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(:name)
end
```

---

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Select service category" %>
    <br>

    <%= collection_select(:service, :name, ServiceMenu.all, :name, :name, {:prompt => true }) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I create a new service, only the tech_id is recorded but not the service_menu_id.
How can I create a new service that would record both tech and service_menu ids at once to the services table?

Any help is appreciated.

> EDIT 7/3 2:55 PM EST

@Yen-Ju method didn't work for me at first but now it does. At first I've failed to properly reference the `service_menu_id` in the `services table`.

My `services` db before:

```
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tech_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_menu_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Reason for not working before is there was no `MUL` value under the `KEY` column.

My `services` db now:

```
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tech_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_menu_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This also allowed me to drop the `name` column in the `services` db since it's no longer needed.

Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test the code, but this might work.

First, change your view to set *service_menu_id*

```
    <%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, ServiceMenu.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true }) %>
```

Second, in your controller, allow *service_menu_id* to pass:

```
def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(:service_menu_id)
end
```

Then, when you build your service, the *service_menu_id* will be passed successfully.

Comment: Your method recorded the service_menu_id to the table but now my `:name` column entries are producing `null`. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You need to set **name** of service ? Then just add **<%= f.text_field :name %>** in your form. **collection_select** is used to set the service_menu.

Comment: Upon further review, your method worked. Please see my edit towards the end of my post. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `has_many :through` relationships to your models:

**tech.rb**

```
class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  has_many :service_menus, through: :services
end
```

**service_menu.rb**

```
class ServiceMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  has_many :techs, through: :services
end
```

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tech
  belongs_to :service_menu
end
```

Once you do this, Active Record takes care of the join model (Service) housekeeping for you.  You can demonstrate this in the Rails console:

```
>> tech = Tech.create(name: "bar")
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "techs" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "bar"], ["created_at", "2015-07-03 23:30:26.893615"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-03 23:30:26.893615"]]
   (10.7ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Tech id: 4, name: "bar", created_at: "2015-07-03 23:30:26", updated_at: "2015-07-03 23:30:26">
>> tech.service_menus << ServiceMenu.create(name: "baz")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "service_menus" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "baz"], ["created_at", "2015-07-03 23:31:21.045841"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-03 23:31:21.045841"]]
   (18.9ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "services" ("tech_id", "service_menu_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["tech_id", 4], ["service_menu_id", 4], ["created_at", "2015-07-03 23:31:21.072932"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-03 23:31:21.072932"]]
   (33.1ms)  commit transaction
  ServiceMenu Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "service_menus".* FROM "service_menus" INNER JOIN "services" ON "service_menus"."id" = "services"."service_menu_id" WHERE "services"."tech_id" = ?  [["tech_id", 4]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ServiceMenu id: 4, name: "baz", created_at: "2015-07-03 23:31:21", updated_at: "2015-07-03 23:31:21">]>
>> Service.first
  Service Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "services".* FROM "services"  ORDER BY "services"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Service id: 2, tech_id: 4, service_menu_id: 4, created_at: "2015-07-03 23:31:21", updated_at: "2015-07-03 23:31:21">`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've done what you suggested, restarted the server but am experiencing the same symptoms of the service_menu_id not being recorded.

Comment: What happens when you create instances in the console?  If that works, but your code doesn't, I would look at @Pavan's answer for suggestions for your controller and view.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. Everything that pertains to this function is listed above. I'm unsure exactly how to build this relationship inside the console. Pavan's method involves manually entering in a `:name` value which is prohibited since these are predefined values entered in by admins only.

Comment: Working on reproducing this in a test project but needed a special inflection to avoid plural of tech = teches.  If I get time tonight I'll post findings.

Comment: Thank you for providing these details. greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following changes.

Add `service_menu_id` in your `servuce_params`.

```
def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(:name, :service_menu_id)
end
```

And change your view code like this

```
<%= simple_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Select service category" %>
    <br>

    <%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, ServiceMenu.all, :name, :name, {:prompt => true }) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The name from the `collection_select` needs to be recorded to the db not the `:name` value from the `f.text_field`. Also the `service_menu_id` returns a value of `0` every time I create a new `service`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use postrgesql, you could read this [ActiveRecord documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) in `1.6 Composite Types` and use `composite types` for Your task.

For example:

```
CREATE TYPE full_service_id AS
(
  tech_id INTEGER,
  service_menu_id_ INTEGER
);

# db/migrate/20140207133952_create_services.rb
execute <<-SQL
CREATE TYPE full_service_id AS
    (
      tech_id INTEGER,
      service_menu_id_ INTEGER
    );
SQL
create_table :services do |t|
  t.column full_service_id
end

# app/models/service.rb
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tech, foreign_key: 'full_service_id.tech_id'
  belongs_to :service_menu, foreign_key: 'full_service_id.service_menu_id_'
end

# Usage
Service.create full_service_id: "#{tech_id},#{service_menu_id_}"
service = Service.first
service.full_service_id # => "(1,1)"
service.full_service_id = "(2,2)"
service.save!
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using sqlite for this test application but my main is mysql.